# Selenium, The method click() in the type WebElement is not applicable for the argument(String)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have problem. I have error "The method click() in the type WebElement is not applicable for the argument(String)"
I checked my java compiler version 1.8

Error is  in line

```js
driver.findElement(By.id(ID_dpd)).click(dpd);
```

```js
My code:
 
public static void deliverymethod(String dpd,WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException{
        String ID_dpd = "s_method_dpd_standard";
        driver.findElement(By.id(ID_dpd)).click(dpd);
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60)
                fail("timeout");
            try {
                if (driver
                        .findElement(By
                                .xpath("//li[3]/div[2]"))
                        .isDisplayed())
                    break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your click method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `driver.findElement(By.id(ID_dpd)).click();`

Comment: Please upvote this answer in case it solved your problem.

Comment: Please accept this as the answer if it solved your problem so that the question gets marked as answered.